# Electron scattering Monte-carlo: prevent ghost-energy gain

Tags: collision-detection, simulation, montecarlo

I am working on a physics simulation, in which electrons scattter on protons, or get absorbed by them. However this situatuation occurs quite often:

[image: Electron proton interaction]

What I want to do is somehow prevent these situations. What can I do to prevent this apart from really lowering my DT time step size? I am okay just with recognizing this scenario. How is it usually handled?

Thank you for your answers and comments!

Comment: How are you simulating?  Are you just calculating the force, changing the velocity depending on the acceleration, and then changing the position depending on the velocity?  If so, try switching to (eg) [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods).  You will probably get a better simulation with *bigger* steps.

Comment: Clarification:  Runge-Kutta is *so* much better than a naïve implementation that you can get a better simulation despite using bigger steps.  This is a big area of research.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to change to a pred-corr or a Runge-Kutta later anyway, but I first wanted to test the code, and saw that it did this. I hope that moving to a Runge-Kutta from an Euler approach would help, but it should not make that much of a difference, should it?

My problem is implementing it, can you give me and advice?

Comment: +1 for "first test the code".  I think the answer to "how is it usually handled" is "use a better algorithm for calculating the updated state".

Comment: when I wrote something similar for fun, I made the time step size dependent on the speed of the particles such that in one time step they travel some maximum distance. Not the best solution, but if you just want to find a quick fix and later change to a different solver anyhow, it might be worth a try

Comment: I have a class for charged particles, that produce a potential at every point of space. To update a particle, I get the potential from every other charged particle I want to be involved in the calculation, and then calculate the summed potential from which I have the force required. Is it possible to update this approach to be able to handle the RK? 
If I'm correct RK reqires me to calculate potentials coming from predicted particle positions. How would I account for that?